# Java - OpenCV 2.4 MatOfPoint is not accepted as a Mat instance

Tags: java, opencv

I am working on a hand detection program, I found the biggest contour of the hand and then I was trying to calculate moments in order to get the center of gravity of the contour so I used `Imgproc.moments` as a parameter the contour I was passing is an instance of `MatOfPoint` which has an isa relationship with `Mat` so passing that instance to this method should not cause any exceptions, but when I am passing an instance of `MatOfPoint` to `Imgproc.moments`I get the exception below which tells me that `MatOfPoint` is not recognized or unsupported

```
OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupported array type) in cvGetMat, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\array.cpp
```

I don't understand why

Comment: Can you please expand this question a little by adding an extract from your code, and clarifying the part 'I get the following exception and...'. ? Which is the exception?

Comment: I edited my question